# Create popup menu with triangle top like Google

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I need to create a popup menu like Google, when click to avatar in google  homepage, it will show a popup with triangle. When i click out of popup, its gone. Who know to do this, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: please share what you tried to do so far. :)

Comment: Could you show an image of the popup?

Comment: You want us to work out the entire code for you, or you just need the triangle?
For the triangle, a good read you can find here > https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

It is actually a pseudo-element, showed up by setting :before or :after to a parent container.

Comment: Maybe try using an open source library for this: https://github.com/FoundOPS/popover

Comment: @designarti I tried this link but i want to handle click and triangle stick with a div that contain my content(profile name or stuff)